# "Analog" version of Kung-Fu Chess?

Tags: chess

Kung-Fu Chess is a real-time chess variant without turns where players may freely move their pieces, subject to a delay period of a few seconds after a move during which a piece cannot be moved again. The current online version of [Kung-Fu Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung-Fu_Chess) is Judo Chess.

Is there an "analog" version of Kung-Fu Chess which can be played on a standard chess board (i.e., not on a computer)? Is this even feasible or would it be impossible to implement?

Answer (score 3):

At first this seemed very infeasible to me.

- You would need a 3 second timer for every piece.
- You need a way to prevent simultaneous claims of single board spaces.

After giving it some thought, I came up with a possible implementation. You would need a board with a socket for each square. When a piece is inserted into this socket, it is held in place by the socket for 3 seconds. Each piece would then need an indicator so you can see whether or not it can be moved (based on the status of the socket) and a button to remove it within the 3 second timeframe in case it's been captured.

Two people simultaneously using both hands to move 32 pieces on a 50x50cm chess board still seems like a bad idea. The board would have to be a bit bigger than a normal chess board, with more distance between the pieces. This will mitigate the problem but for the most part this will have to be "part of the game".

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is an interesting suggestion. I wonder if the 3 second timer could be approximated by ruling players cannot make consecutive moves with the same piece. Another idea that just occurred to me is to randomize movement timing, using dice or drawing cards from a deck. For example, players roll a 6 sided die to determine if a piece may be moved, with no limit on # of die rolls. On a 1 or 2 the player may move a piece. Of course this would result in a chess game with frantic dice rolling, which could be distracting.